# PayPal Sandbox API SSL handshake error HTTPS request

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

With new changes in paypal , it started throwing SSL handshake exceptions those who are using old system. "**PayPal SSL Certificate Changes**"
https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-ssl-certificate-changes/

This may help someone. After i got SSL Handshake exception , i spent a hell lot of time to resolve it.

Here is the Exception :

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   handshake_failure

**Solution :**

Requirements to resolve this issue :

Start from Jan 19, all sandbox API endpoint need to

```
 1.) Use TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 connection

 2.) Upgrade to SHA-256 and use the G5 root certificate to make the HTTPS connection
```

**Point 1 Solution:**

```
If you are using java 6 then better upgrade it to java 7

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

For my case i am using java 7 so TLSv1 (default) for JDK 7.

We have to enable it manually while starting server 

**-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2** passed as vm argument.
```

**Point 2 Solution  :**

```
https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/mpki-for-ssl-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=SO5624

G5 cerificate import: Save it as test.cer

Go to java home/bin then run this command 

keytool -importcert   -file C:/test.cer
```

create sanbox account. Get the facilator password and signature pass it as parameters

```
String encodedData = "USER=XXX-facilitator_api1.XXX.XXX"
                         + "&PWD=XXXXXXXXXXXX"
                         + "&SIGNATURE=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-"
                         + "&VERSION=95"                         
                         + "&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout"
                         + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Authorization"
                         + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0="+URLEncoder.encode("Testing","UTF-8")
                         + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0="+URLEncoder.encode("Testing","UTF-8")
                         + "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0="+URLEncoder.encode("99","UTF-8")
                         + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT="+URLEncoder.encode("99","UTF-8")
                         + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE="+URLEncoder.encode("USD","UTF-8")
                         + "&LOCALECODE=en_GB"                        
                         + "&RETURNURL=google.com"
                         + "&CANCELURL=google.co.in"
                         + "&LOGOIMG=imageurl"; 

String responsepaypal = getHTMLcontent("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp",encodedData ,"UTF-8");
String token = responsepaypal.toString().replaceAll("TOKEN=(.*?)&TIMESTAMP.*", "$1");//***Token for post request on paypal***




public static String getHTMLcontent(String url,String urlParameters, String encodingDef) throws IOException  {      

            URL obj = new URL(url);     
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection(); 
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");       
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(urlParameters.length())); 
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"); 
            con.setRequestProperty("Host", "api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com"); 
            con.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1"); 
            con.setRequestProperty("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
            //con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");     
            con.setDoOutput(true); 
            con.setDoInput(true); 
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());  
            output.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            output.close();

            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream( con.getInputStream() ); 

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line;
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            input.close(); 


            return sb.toString();
        }}
```

Follow the steps out here clearly mentioned:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleAuthPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: I get the SSL Erro (in fact SSL handshake aborted). I'm on Mac using Android Studio. I installed the certificate, but after that, where do you put your code? Do you have to put it inside your app and use it each time or is it a code you create in a separate APP and that will only init one time your sandbox account? But in that case what will happend in production mode? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing paypal using the sandbox account and I was getting the same error. I upgraded to java 8 and the error was not there anymore.